# Upgrading to Access 2007, Trust Center Issue

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

Is there a way to automatically set Trust Center locations in a network environment when upgrading to Access 2007?

Comment: not sure this is a programming question....

Comment: Registry settings can be altered in VBA code (though I'm not sure that's the best approach), so it seems like it's potentially a programming question.

Comment: Oh, and sometimes it's helpful to post in a programming forum in order to discover that the problem is *not* a programming problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your Group Policy tools to force local and network locations.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc178948.aspx

Note that if this fails, it is usually a Group Policy distribution error.